# HTML-Aria-label not accepting on anchor tag

Tags: html

I am trying to apply Aria-label but it is throwing error when I try to validate it for STQC.

> **2.4.4 Link Purpose (In Context)**
>
> The WAI-ARIA 'aria-label' attributes should be descriptive of the links they are labelling, since the 'aria-label' will overwrite other link text.

Here is my sample code

```
<li>test1
  <a  href="/test/abc/0219/test.pdf" aria-label="-detail for abc" title="test"  target="_blank">-Click here</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Did you find the answer to this? I put an aria-label on an a tag and it doesn't render in the DOM

Answer (score 2):

`aria-label` can be used with `a` elements. Not sure what are you referring when you mention STQC, but you can see a descriptive [list of elements that can be used with aria-label](https://www.aditus.io/aria/aria-label/#how-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

It's an attribute designed to help assistive technology (e.g. screen readers) attach a label to an otherwise anonymous HTML element.

aria-label does much the same thing, but it's for those cases where it isn't practical or desirable to have a label on screen. Take the MDN [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute):

```
<button aria-label="Close" onclick="myDialog.close()">X</button>
```

Most people would be able to infer visually that this button will close the dialog. A blind person using assistive technology might just hear "X" read aloud, which doesn't mean much without the visual clues. aria-label explicitly tells them what the button will do.

Comment: Yes i am aware of that.but the thing is i am giving descriptive information in aria-label,but even then, it is not validate.That is the problem i am facing.I am not sure that if i can ignore it for STQC,as auditor will count the number of error, he will not be interested to understand the logic or will check my code.I have to close this type of error and i have 200+ count for that.

Answer (score 0):

Move the aria-label inside the li tag

```
<li aria-label="-detail for abc"><a href="">click here</a></li>
```